# Send an email when succesful Paypal payment (with a Paypal button) has been done

Tags: php, email, paypal, shopping-cart

I'd like that an email should be sent to a customer if the payment on a Paypal button has been successful. Something like :

```
Dear customer, 
Thank you for your purchase.
... 
Thank you,
....
```

How to do it ? I see how to add a "return URL" when succesful payement, but I don't see an option for sending an email (in Paypal button creation options).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't this be something that your own code (ie, the return URL) does rather than paypal?

Comment: @subroutines, do you have an example of how to do this with Paypal IPN ?

Comment: @JosBas Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/)

Comment: @subroutines : Can I do IPN if I only use a standard simple Paypal html button `<form> ... </form>`?
If so where can I enable IPN ?

Comment: I don't really understand how it works, even with the doc... Can someone provide a simple example?
1. I click on a HTML Paypal button `<form>`
2. I pay
3. Then where should I configure the IPN ? On which page ?

Comment: @JosBas You need to create your own page, ie `my_ipn.php`. This is the page paypal reads automatically when there's a payment. You must also let paypal know of this page by including `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="my_ipn.php" />` in your <form>. Refer to the doc for sample php code for your `my_ipn.php`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your own page that sends the email.  Perhaps thankyou.aspx.
2. Set the PayPal return URL to thankyou.aspx

Ta da